# How to Show Fragments based on user role stored in Shared Preference after successfull login

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I am getting user role in response after successfull login using `Volley`.I have stored role in `SharedPreferences`.

```
JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, whoAmIUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    try {
                                        String whoIAm=response.getString("group");
                                        Log.i("response",whoIAm);
                                        edit.putString("whoAmI",whoIAm);
                                        edit.apply();
                                    }catch (JSONException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                }
                            })
```

I retrieve the user role in every Fragment/Activity from preferences.

```
prefs=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            myAccess=prefs.getString("whoAmI","empty");
```

Based on user role I need to show the user Activity/Fragments further.
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to illustrate what you have done so far. Do you really need a different activity or fragment for each role? Does each role require a completely different layout? Or is there just different data for each role?

Answer (score 0):

use polymorphism. An Object can be assigned to be any SubObject of its class.
so the `Fragment fragment;` can be any kind of fragment, because every Fragment you create inherits from the `Fragment` class

for example:

```
Fragment fragment;

if(SharedPreferences == "admin") {
    fragment = new AdminFragment();
} else {
    fragment = new UserFragment();
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement is the key here, not polymorphism per se.

Comment: polymorphism as of my knowledge does play a role though, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are using polymorphism by assigning an instance of a child class to a reference to a super class type. However, this is not the important part of your answer, in my opinion. The important part is that an if statement can be used to determine which Fragment subclass to use.